# Integrating Google test results report with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, googletest

I am using Google test 1.8 and have the xml report in JUnit format ( I read from other sources)
generated using ./a.out --gtest_output=xml:result.xml in my Linux machine.

however when I add this report as part of post build action , choosing Publish JUnit test result report, in the text box in jenkins, I specified "result.xml " file .

Built it and getting the following error 
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed

```
2 FAILED TESTS
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /home/nelrtu/workspace       /NELRTU_CI_BUILD at hudson.remoting.Channel@d88e287:SAME_SLAVE: java.io.IOException: Remote call on SOME_SLAVE failed
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:103)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:126)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:148)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on SOME_SLAVE failed
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:789)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:979)
... 14 more`enter code here`
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unable to load resource hudson/tasks/junit/Messages.properties
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findResource(RemoteClassLoader.java:397)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096)
at java.lang.Class.getResource(Class.java:2267)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:107)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:128)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:128)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.format(ResourceBundleHolder.java:170)
at hudson.tasks.junit.Messages.JUnitResultArchiver_NoTestReportFound(Messages.java:368)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:140)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:107)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:152)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at ......remote call to RTU_CI_SLAVE(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:252)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
... 15 more
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to write to /home/nelrtu/.jenkins/cache/jars/FB/BD3521667259673E8728695E2AC347.jar
at hudson.remoting.AsyncFutureImpl.get(AsyncFutureImpl.java:75)
at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findResource(RemoteClassLoader.java:389)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096)
at java.lang.Class.getResource(Class.java:2267)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:107)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:128)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.get(ResourceBundleHolder.java:128)
at org.jvnet.localizer.ResourceBundleHolder.format(ResourceBundleHolder.java:170)
at hudson.tasks.junit.Messages.JUnitResultArchiver_NoTestReportFound(Messages.java:368)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:140)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:107)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:152)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write to /home/<User-director>/.jenkins/cache/jars/FB/BD3521667259673E8728695E2AC347.jar
at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:112)
at hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$1.run(JarCacheSupport.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on channel failed
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:789)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:249)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.writeJarTo(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.retrieve(FileSystemJarCache.java:74)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1131)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
at ......remote call to channel(Native Method)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:252)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
... 8 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I pressume , jenkins is accepting the Xml format generated by Google test , since I see the log message as "Recording test results"

Comment: I think your issue rather comes from `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, do you have enough resources allocated to your jenkins?

Comment: have you tried the xunit pluigin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin

Comment: I am Sorry! forgot to reply to this. Yes finally instlaling Xunit pluging in jenkins and selecting the Googltest1.6 as the results XML solve this.